# Haartraining - Opencv

Tags: opencv

I am working on a haar-training project where I am trying to detect pen.. There are 41 positive images and 80 negative images. I have started the process but it stopped in 16th node for the past 1 and half hours. I don`t know whether something wrong has happened or its just the process that taking the time.. Can anyone tell me how can I go about it?

Answer (score 0):

My hair trainings have lasted for a day or so. Have you seen multiple steps / iterations occurring.
Perhaps you should use more samples, I used 2000+ false and hundreds of positive images to detect eyes. The iterations start really fast, but are taking longer and longer to run.

good luck I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks so much for the response. Iterations happened till the 15 nodes very quickly. And after that It seem to have stopped. Any guess why? Hope it is nothing but the process delay..

Comment: I'm very much afraid you have to be patient, if it's running so far it will probably continue. My few hairtrainings also took quite some time around iteration/node 15 - 16.